# Windows dir command for the web directory

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a Windows `dir` command that works on web sites?

For example something like;

```
dir www.stack.com
```

Something to run from command prompt. I was wondering if i could use something like 
`dir/s c:\*.txt`

on websites to list a type of file.

Thanks.

Comment: you cant.But you can try with `wget -O - www.stack.com` (just get wget foe windows and see what it can do)

Comment: Most websites (these days) don't support directory listing.

Comment: thanks npocmaka. can't see any icon to upvote/accept ur answer. new here, appreciate ur help.